# Pandas: Count rows in table based on two columns, using one columns' value

Tags: pandas

I currently have the following dataframe:

```
SN             Gender    Purchase
Name 1         Female    1.14
Name 2         Female    2.50
Name 3         Male      7.77
Name 1         Female    2.74
Name 3         Male      4.58
Name 3         Male      9.99
Name 1         Female    5.55
Name 2         Female    1.20
```

I am trying to figure out how to just get a *count*, not a Dataframe, from a table like this. The count must be based on gender (so, how many males are there?), but must be unique by name (SN). So, in this instance, I would have 1 male and 2 females. I have tried multiple ways...valuecounts from the data frame, unique from the dataframe, etc. but I keep getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can achieve this.

The simplest one would be to use `pd.crosstab` to get a cross tabulation (count) of the values:

```
pd.crosstab(df["SN"], df["Gender"])

Gender  Female  Male
SN                  
Name 1       3     0
Name 2       2     0
Name 3       0     3
```

Another way is to use `DataFrame.value_counts()` which cameabout in `pandas` version >= `1.1.0`. Instead of a cross tabulation, this returns a Series whose values are the counts of data per unique index combination. The index is a `MultiIndex` referring to unique combinations of `"SN" and "Gender"`

```
df.value_counts(["SN", "Gender"])

SN      Gender
Name 3  Male      3
Name 1  Female    3
Name 2  Female    2
dtype: int64
```

If you're operating with a pandas version older than `1.1.0` you can use a combination of `groupby` and `value_counts`. This performs a functionally equivalent operation as `DataFrame.value_counts` so we get the same output:

```
df.groupby("SN")["Gender"].value_counts()

SN      Gender
Name 1  Female    3
Name 2  Female    2
Name 3  Male      3
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

---

Edit: If you want to only count the number of unique `"SN"` for each gender, you can use `nunique()` instead of `value_counts`:

```
unique_genders = df.groupby(["Gender"])["SN"].nunique()

print(unique_genders)
Gender
Female    2
Male      1
Name: SN, dtype: int64
```

Then you can extract each:

```
>>> unique_genders["Female"]
2

>>> unique_geners["Male"]
1
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I just want to feed the number into a variable? Like, for instance, num_males = ... and count only the males that are unique?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my answer with an example of how to count the number of unique `"SN"` for each `"gender"`

Comment: Thank you again! Do I have to feed in a particular module of some sort in order to make this work? "nunique" is new to me. I've used "unique" on a singular column, but not more than one. I did try using what you wrote, but I am getting a syntax error. 

Note that earlier in my code, using jupyter notebook, I added "import pandas as pd", "import os", and "import csv". I set "csvpath" to the location of the .csv file. And then I set the name of the dataframe like this: df_purchase_data = pd.read_csv(csvpath).

Comment: Nope this should work right off the bat with the syntax I have there (at least it does for me). Can you share the specific syntax error your're receiving? `nunique` is a `pandas.Series` and `pandas.DataFrame` method.

Comment: I have called this dataframe name easily to get results for counting all rows or an average. Your code is giving me a name error?:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-06dcaa652bb4> in <module>

      2 
----> 3 unique_genders_df = df_purchase_data.groupby(["Gender"])["SN"].nunique()
      4 print(unique_genders_df)
      5 

NameError: name 'df_purchase_data' is not defined

Comment: The error you're receiving is because you're trying to operate on `df_purchase_data` which is a variable that you have not defined yet. Make somewhere in your code you create a variable called `df_purchase_data` before trying to use it.

Comment: You're right! It actually was defined, but I had to re-run all my lines in the Jupyter Notebook to get it to work. And now, I'm good to go! Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome! Since this worked for you, would you mind selecting this answer as "correct" so future individuals who have a similar question can easily find the solution?